# Converting a particular date format into string in SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to achieve this formt from sql server. I have tried with various things but not able to achieve this
Ultimately this should be a string datatype

```
 '23 Apr, 2018 2:59 PM'
```

I am trying to achieve this as below:

```
CONVERT(CHAR(12), dbo.fn_GetDateIntime(cl.createdDate), 107)holla,
convert(char(3), dbo.fn_GetDateIntime(cl.createdDate), 0)MonthPart,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), dbo.fn_GetDateIntime(cl.createdDate), 114) TimePart,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `format` function -

```
select format(getdate(), 'dd MMM, yyyy hh:mm tt')
```

Output -

```
25 Apr, 2018 01:59 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `convert()` function:

```
select convert(varchar(20), date, 113) as datestring
```

You can also use `format()` function but not best for performance perspective

```
select format(getdate(), 'dd MMM, yyyy hh:mm tt') as datestring
```

Answer (score 0):

> We can achieve this by two methods `CONVERT` and `FORMAT` below is
>   example of both. I hope this will help you...

**1st way**

```
select CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),100) as [Date Time String]
 --100 is datetime default sql format 'mon dd yyyy hh:miAM/PM'
```

Output -

```
Apr 25 2018  1:23PM
```

**Second way**

```
    select FORMAT(getdate(), 'dd MMM, yyyy hh:mm tt') as [Date Time String]
     -- In first parameter we have to pass date 
     -- In second parameter we need to pass date forma in string
```

Output -

```
25 Apr, 2018 01:59 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
select convert(varchar(20),format(getdate(),'dd MMM yyyy HH:MM tt'))
```